# Possible to install PySide or PyQt on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, pyqt, pyside, ghost.py

I am not able to install PySide and cannot figure out how to install PyQt on Heroku.

I need PySide in order to use Ghost.py.

Here is what I include in my requirements.txt:

```
Ghost.py==0.1b3    
PySide==1.2.2
```

And here is the error when pushing to Heroku:

```
Python architecture is 64bit

       error: Failed to find cmake. Please specify the path to cmake with --cmake parameter.

       ----------------------------------------
       Cleaning up...
       Command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_u30455/PySide/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-LqhYm6-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_u30455/PySide
       Storing debug log for failure in /app/.pip/pip.log

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
```

Thanks for your help ahead of time!

Comment: Since Heroku doesn't run an X11 server, it's highly unlikely you'll be able to install (Py)QT on it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to install PySide or PyQt on Heroku.

My workaround was to use PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org/) with BeautifulSoup.